# Visual studio in stuck Generating code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

When I build a c++ project with Visual Studio the process get in stuck while *Generating Code*:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: myWrapper, Configuration: Release Win32 ------ 
1>  funzioni_ausiliarie.cpp 
1>  myWrapperFunction.cpp 
1>  NLP_eta_tre_spline.cpp 
1>  Generating Code...
```

MSVS is still responding and seems to being working, but I waited more than 10 minutes and it didn't finished. Finally I canceled the process.
Instead, building in debug mode it finisces in 20 seconds.

I also tried to disable "Whole Program Optimization" and "Multi-processor compilation" in C++ compile options and I left empty the parameter "Link Time Code Generation" in linker options (obviously for release configuration) but the problem still occurs.

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

I applied this http://www.gamedev.net/topic/627047-visual-studio-generating-code-infinitely/. That is: in prject properties, setting the C++ -> Optimization -> Optimization to "Disable".

Now it works properly.
I also setted to original values "Whole Program Optimization", "Multi-processor compilation" and "Link Time Code Generation" and it works.

Comment: This solution worked for me. But I wonder, why is the problem happening. Maybe a bug in VS?

Comment: Ouch. Having do disable optimizations wholesale is a big hammer.

Answer (score 1):

With VS2017 (15.5.0), I ran into a problem where building a third-party library for Release hung the compiler at "Generating Code" for tens of minutes, and I gave up waiting. I had been using Whole Program Optimization, but turning that off didn't help.

I also had been using Optimization set to Maximum Speed (/O2). I changed it to **Custom** and turned on **/Ob2**, **/Oi**, **/Os**, and **/Oy**. The build completed in a few seconds. For the library I was using, that was good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I recently saw this and waited over 15 minutes as well... the key to me was noticing that the "Building" circle with arrows on it was still orbiting, so I thought I would give it some time... and it finally moved on:

[image]