# Visual Studio 2019 "C1001 internal compiler error" only in Release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm getting a C1001 error while attempting to build in Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.7.2. This is a C++ project that has previously built fine until a change set I am attempting to build today.

The exact error is as follows: (with project specific path redacted)

```
1>d:\work\[...](82): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

1>(compiler file 'd:\agent\_work\3\s\src\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 187)
```

Notes below:

1. The error only happens in Release. Debug builds and runs.
2. If I turn off all optimizations in Release the error goes away.
3. The location where the error occurs seems to be unrelated to recent changes I have made to the project i.e. VS is reporting the error in a translation unit that had been building without problem until unrelated changes in another TU were made.
4. The location where the error occurs seems to not actually be problematic in the sense that if I comment out the implementation of the function there and just return a default value from the function so that the program is syntactically correct, the error occurs in the next the function in the same file.
5. Turning off Whole Program Optimization and Link Time Code Generation *does not* fix the problem.

Comment: Internal compiler error is a compiler bug. You need to file a bug with VS.

Comment: how does that work if it is impossible to create a minimal reproducible example though? This is a fairly large codebase that is all of a sudden erroring out during code generation.

Comment: You'll have to hand over your code to Microsoft to get some help on this.... [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thank you for adding the exact error message to your question.  See me response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SUGGESTIONS**

Please:

1. Update your post with exact error text (if available)
2. Post your question to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/ as well
3. See if any of these links are applicable:

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/710576/visual-studio-2019-1622-fatal-error-c1001-in-32-bi.html
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/165975b4-35e9-4b40-9524-e656a4e2f359/fatal-error-c1001-an-internal-error-has-occurred-in-the-compiler?forum=visualstudiogeneral
- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/664162/ice-on-valid-code-after-upgrading-to-1620.html

4. One way to notify Microsoft Support like this:

   *MSVS > Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem*
5. Here is a complete list of MSVS support options: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/

---

**Update:**

Thank you for copying/pasting the exact error message:

```
1>d:\work\[...](82): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>(compiler file 'd:\agent\_work\3\s\src\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 187)
```

This is the MSVS file causing the error C1001: `vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c`

This is an existing Microsoft trouble report:

> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/210332/c1001-internal-error-compiler-file-fddvctoolscompi.html
>
> Hi Roger,
>
> Thanks for reporting the bug, and including an excellently
> self-contained repro, so quickly. I've investigated and this seems to
> be the same issue as
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/209359/ice-with-fpfast-in-156-and-msvc-daily-1413263051-p.html.
>
> I'm closing this as a duplicate just so that people can collect
> context and work-around advice in the same location, and when the
> other bug is marked fixed, you can assume that this one is too.
>
> Thanks again,
>
> Aaron Gorenstein
> Software Engineer II

Searching for this error message/source module, I also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63435683/421195

Please post back if either of these work for you!

Comment: thanks for the link ... setting optimization to custom and applying "'/Ob2  /Oi  /Os  /Oy" allows me to compile succefully in x86 Release. (this error only exhibited in x86 ... i didnt know that for sure when I wrote the question so left that detail out; but now I have verified that x64 builds without problem). the program is now ~2x slower so this is a work-around not a solution, obviously, but it is better than completely turning off optimizations by at least a factor of 2.

Comment: Just seen this in release x64 in 16.9.4.

Comment: Release x64 @ 16.9.4 +1